# What replaces "ntpq" in CentOS 8?

Tags: ntp, centos8

I want to install this utility `ntpq` as described here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-bsd-is-ntp-client-working/

It prints all connected NTP servers and various NTP sync measurements.

Cant find it for Centos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as of rhel8, the NTP protocol is implemented by the chronyd daemon. you can use `chronyc sources`

Comment: chrony was the preferred implementation at RHEL/Centos 7 already, or even 6. It seems that it has become the *only* NTP server in 8.